# Handlebar Issues

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I am currently trying to run a GET operation but my code doesn't seem to work. I already have the simple set up done but when I click the button I created to request the data from a simple .JSON file I made I keep getting "0 documents retrieved". Could anyone assist with this? here is my code attached in screenshots. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Handlebars -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get Request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>GET Request</h2S>
    <div class="results">
        {{#each data}}
        <p> {{first_name}} {{last_name}} </p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML -

```
 <h2>GET Request</h2>
<p>
 <a href="/api/user"
 data-selector="results">Load user data</a> 
 <form action="/api/user" method="GET"></form>
</p>
<div class="results"></div>
```

JavaScript -

```
    const express  = require("express")
const app = express();
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
 
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());

 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/api/user', function(req, res) { 
    mongo.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, database) {
        const db = database.db('test');
        db.collection('users').find() 
            .toArray(function(err, result) { 
            if (err) { 
                throw err; 
            } 
            console.log(result.length + ' documents retrieved.'); 
            //res.json(result); 
            res.render('user', { data:result, layout:false})
            database.close(); 
        }); 
    }); 
});


app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile('./public/hello.html',{root: __dirname});
});

 
const port = 8900;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Listening to server: http://localhost:${port}`)
```

JSON -

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
        "first_name": "Robert",
        "last_name": "Swanson"
    },
    "title": "Some Dude"
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code to the question.

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe The code is all attached in the links in my question but since I'm new here I'll guess that is probably the wrong way of doing it. I will edit the post and show the code physically.